# Run WHERE over an Average aggregation result - postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, average, aggregation

I have the following query that gets the papers grade listing.

```
SELECT DISTINCT papers.paper_id, papers.paper_title, AVG(paper_judge_participations.paper_judge_participation_score) AS final_grade,
(SELECT array_agg(paper_author_name) FROM paper_authors as authors WHERE authors.paper_id=papers.paper_id )::varchar as paper_author_name
FROM papers 
FULL JOIN paper_categories ON paper_categories.paper_category_id=papers.paper_category_id
LEFT JOIN paper_judge_participations ON papers.paper_id = paper_judge_participations.paper_id 
WHERE ((papers.paper_note IS NULL AND final_grade >= 7) OR (papers.paper_note IS NOT NULL AND papers.paper_note >= 7)) AND papers.paper_category_id = 1
GROUP BY papers.paper_id ORDER BY final_grade, papers.paper_note;
```

I want to see if the final_grade variable from the the averae result is more than 7 but I get the error:

```
ERROR:  column "final_grade" does not exist
LINE 6: WHERE ((papers.paper_note IS NULL AND final_grade >= 7) OR (...
```

How can I use the average result on my `WHERE` condition?

Comment: AVG() is not allowed on the where clauses. ): @vkp

Comment: You need to put the avg condition in a "HAVING" clause, which comes after the GROUP BY

Comment: I'm new to SQL. Can you please answer the question with the script, @mlinth ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `distinct` is unnecessary in the `SELECT`.  Also you need to move the logic to the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT p.paper_id, p.paper_title,
       AVG(pjp.paper_judge_participation_score) AS final_grade,
       (SELECT string_agg(paper_author_name)
        FROM paper_authors pa
        WHERE pa.paper_id = p.paper_id
       ) as paper_author_name
FROM papers p LEFT JOIN
     paper_categories pc
     ON pc.paper_category_id = p.paper_category_id LEFT JOIN 
     paper_judge_participations pjp
     ON p.paper_id = pjp.paper_id 
HAVING p.paper_category_id = 1
GROUP BY p.paper_id
HAVING (p.paper_note IS NULL AND final_grade >= 7) OR
       (p.paper_note IS NOT NULL AND p.paper_note >= 7) AND 
ORDER BY final_grade, p.paper_note;
```

Comments:

- The `FULL OUTER JOIN` is being turned into a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` by the `WHERE` clause.  So, you might as well be explicit.
- Instead of doing `array_agg()` and converting the results to a string, how about just using `string_agg()`?
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and read.
- And of course, the conditions on the final grade have been moved to the `HAVING` clause.  The condition on the group stays in the `WHERE`.

Personally, I find it strange that you are using a correlated subquery for one aggregation and explicit aggregation for the other.  I suppose that is a matter of preference.  Under the circumstance, you might consider using a correlated subquery for both.

Comment: The system I'm working uses a old version of postgresql and some functions like string_agg() don't exist.

Comment: I ended using the having, and it's working now. Thanks.